# How to enable Java in Firefox 11.0 on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, java

I'm using an app called ScreenCast-o-matic.com and it was working fine before but now saying Java is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open the Add-ons Manager.
2. Click `Plugins` in the menu on the left.
3. Search for the Java plugin and click the `Enable` button.

Comment: Also, when I tried to reinstall Java I found this page which has that tip and others.  http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml